# Calculate offset rotation to allow gears to mesh correctly?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

For each Gear, I have the following properties:

- Radius : The length between the center of the gear and the edge.
- OffsetAngle : The angle of this gear to the parent gear. 0 when no parent.
- CenterX : The center of the gear.
- CenterY : The center of the gear.
- NumberOfTeeth : The total number of teeth for this gear.
- ToothInterval : The angle separating each tooth.
- Parent : Contains all of the above properties for the gear this gear is connected to.

I need to calculate the correct offset rotation for each gear so that the teeth line up correctly. See the attached image for a visual guide. The rotation will need to refer to the parent's rotation, and when there is no parent (The 32 Teeth gear in the middle of the picture) the rotation is 0.

[image: Visual aid showing gear positions]

I cannot for the life of me work out a formula that would work for this - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Solution:

```
this.rotation  = function() { 
    if (this.parent) {
        return -this.parent.rotation()*this.ratio() + this.toothsize()/2;
    } else { return gearRot; }
}
```

Comment: Try: http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: what is `toothsize` measured in?  pixels?  degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag each gear as either 'even' or 'odd'.  Restrict your gears such that no gear can connect to one with the same tag.  That is, 'even' gears cannot connect to any gears except 'odd' ones, and 'odd' ones can only connect to 'even" ones.  This will correspond to the parity of the depth of the gear in the data structure you're using to describe the overall structure.  It will also be helpful to determine which way the gears actually turn with respect to each other.

Rotate all of the "odd" gears by 1/2 of a cycle.  So if you have 32 teeth, each cycle is 2π/32 = π/16 radians in length, so add a rotational factor of 2π/64 = π/32 radians.

Comment: My code actually determined the reversal of the gear depending on the parent's reversal, implementing what you suggested automatically. Reversal was set to be false if there was no parent.

`this.rotation  = function() { 
  if (this.parent) {
   return -this.parent.rotation()*this.ratio() + this.toothsize()/2;
  } else { return globalGearRot; }
 }`

Answer (score 2):

The formula you provided as solution works only for gear positions where the teeth of two connected gears with rotation 0 are perfectly aligned like the situation is in your image. For arbitrary positions you also need to calculate the angle beween both centers and rotate one of the gears by that value plus eventually - as @andand pointed out - "half a tooth" if the rotated gear has an odd number of teeth. A while ago I wrote a similar gear demo:

[JavaScript Gears](http://kirox.de/html/Gears.html)

Have a look at GearView.setPos() in the source code. Change the number of teeth with »,«, ».« or mouse wheel.

Comment: http://ruirize.co.uk/hacks/sbgears/

This is what I worked out after accepting the answer above this one.

Comment: Great, these are nice gears! I'm so tired to see gear images where the teeth not even nearly match.